# Custom number format comparison operator issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to get all values equal an above 80 to be in green, and zeros between 1 and 79 to be on red and all values that are 0 to be blank or color white (either is ok).

I've tried the following ones but zeros are keep showing in red since I cant insert if =0 or something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
[=0][white]0; [<80][red]0"▼"; [color 50]0"▲"
```

[image]